# Java crashed with an unrecoverable error, now xrdp crashes with "oh no, something has gone wrong"

Tags: xrdp

I was playing Minecraft on a Windows client via PaperMC on an Ubuntu 22.04 when suddenly it crashed out with an unrecoverable Java error. After the system restarted, remote desktop via xrdp, which has worked fine up until now, says "oh no, something has gone wrong" after the xrdp login screen and stops working. I can log in on console just fine. How do I find out what the unexpected problem might be and proceed to fix it?

systemctl status shows that xrdp is running properly:

Apr 30 11:19:58 mc5600 systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...

Apr 30 11:19:58 mc5600 xrdp[1050]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1

Apr 30 11:19:58 mc5600 xrdp[1050]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0

Apr 30 11:19:58 mc5600 xrdp[1050]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done

Apr 30 11:19:58 mc5600 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Can't open PID file /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid (yet?) after start: Oper>

Apr 30 11:19:59 mc5600 systemd[1]: Started xrdp daemon.

Apr 30 11:20:00 mc5600 xrdp[1062]: [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1062

Apr 30 11:20:00 mc5600 xrdp[1062]: [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1

Apr 30 11:20:00 mc5600 xrdp[1062]: [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0

Apr 30 11:20:00 mc5600 xrdp[1062]: [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done

then i try to connect from the windows client and the status changes to several errors that xrdp_mcs_recv_failed:

Apr 30 11:15:47 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [INFO ] started connecting

Apr 30 11:15:47 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket

Apr 30 11:15:48 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=16002 connected to X11rdp_pid=16005 X11rd>

Apr 30 11:15:48 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [INFO ] connected ok

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_recv: xrdp_mcs_recv failed

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_recv: xrdp_sec_recv failed

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] libxrdp_process_data: xrdp_rdp_recv failed

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_data_in: xrdp_process_loop failed

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed

Apr 30 11:15:53 mc5600 xrdp[16002]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed

That file references, xrdp.pid contains only a simple number, what is its significance and is that the problem?

magarity@mc5600:~$ sudo cat /run/xrdp/xrdp.pid

1062

Comment: ok apparently that pid file has nothing to do with the crashes, and it disappears when the service is stopped.

Comment: I tried apt purge xrdp, reboot, apt install xrdp but the problem remains.

Comment: These are info that belong in the question not as comments.

Comment: Thanks, you're an enormous help.Is there anyone on this site who can try to help diagnose problems?